# Shell console command in VBA Access doesn't work properly

Tags: vba, shell, ms-access, cmd, console

I have a big issue with my code, which i'vre created by using already known/someone solution.

What's going on:
I need a code which will give me an extract of all files, which lastDateModified is older than some specific date. However the best solution will be if i will received those file names in array (don't know how to do that"

Problem:
When I enter a command in the console, it gives me the list of files correctly.

Whereas when I place it in Access it gets me text:

*Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.*

I:\Documents\Access>

Code:

```vb
Public Sub TestCommandLine()
    Const lngCancelled_c As Long = 0
    Dim strCmd As String

    strCmd = "cmd.exe forfiles /P directory /S /D +01/04/2015) > directory2"
    CommandLine strCmd, False
End Sub

Public Function CommandLine(command As String, Optional ByVal keepAlive As _
Boolean = False, Optional windowState As VbAppWinStyle = 
VbAppWinStyle.vbHide) _
As Boolean

 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Procedure : CommandLine
 ' Author    : Aaron Bush (Oorang)
 ' Date      : 10/02/2007
 ' Purpose   : Provides a simple interface to execute a command lines from VBA.
 ' Input(s)  :
 '               command     : The DOS command you wish to execute.
 '               keepAlive   : Keeps the DOS window open *after* command has been
 '                             executed. Default behavior is to auto-close. (See
 '                             remarks section for additional information.)
 '               windowState : Determines the window state of the DOS prompt
 '                             *during* command execution.
 ' Output    : True if completed with no errors, False if error encountered.
 ' Remarks   : If the windowState property is set to vbHide while the keepAlive
 '             parameter is set to True, then windowState will be changed to
 '             vbNormalFocus.
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

On Error GoTo Err_Hnd
Const lngMatch_c As Long = 0
Const strCMD_c As String = "cmd.exe"
Const strComSpec_c As String = "COMSPEC"
Const strTerminate_c As String = " /c "
Const strKeepAlive_c As String = " /k "
Dim strCmdPath As String
Dim strCmdSwtch As String
    If keepAlive Then
        If windowState = vbHide Then
            windowState = vbNormalFocus
        End If
        strCmdSwtch = strKeepAlive_c
    Else
        strCmdSwtch = strTerminate_c
    End If
    strCmdPath = VBA.Environ$(strComSpec_c)
    If VBA.StrComp(VBA.Right$(strCmdPath, 7), strCMD_c, vbTextCompare) <> _
    lngMatch_c Then
         strCmdSwtch = vbNullString
    End If
    VBA.Shell strCmdPath & strCmdSwtch & command, windowState
    CommandLine = True
    VBA.Shell Nothing
    Exit Function
Err_Hnd:
    CommandLine = False
End Function
```

Do anyone have this issue?

Comment: You're doing something weird here. The `CommandLine` function you're using, uses shell to open a command window. If I read the code you're trying correctly, you're using shell to open a command window, and then `cmd` in that command window to open another command window. That's bound to cause weirdness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this construct

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Find_Files()
    Dim fileDetails() As String
    fileDetails = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c forfiles /P C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestFolder /S /D -19/04/2018").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(fileDetails) To UBound(fileDetails)
        If Not IsEmpty(fileDetails(i)) Then Debug.Print fileDetails(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another question abt same problem - how can i check all files in network drive?

i've tried with

```
cmd /c pushd "network drive path" forfiles /S /D +14/04/2018
```

and it doesnt work, however when i write it in console in seperate lines

```
pushd "network_drive"
forfiles /s /d +10/04/2018
popd
```

then all works.
Any ideas?

SOLVED:

```
fileDetails = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c pushd " & Chr(34) & IMPORT_PATH & FOLDER_PATH & Chr(34) & " & forfiles /S /D +" & s_date & " & popd").StdOut.ReadAll, Chr(10))
```

And it works for net drive

Comment: This should be posted as a new question